# Can't make the decltype specifier work properly inside the lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, grammar, decltype

This piece of code doesn't complie .The compiler remind me that :cannot convert from “initializer list” to “`std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<_Ty, std::allocator<_Ty>>, std::less<_Ty>> &`”.

```
    #include <vector>
    #include <queue>

    int main()
    {
        using namespace std;
        priority_queue<int> que;
        auto func = [&]()
        {
            vector<int> vec;
            que = decltype(que)(vec.begin(),vec.end());
            //cannot convert from“initializer list”to“std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<_Ty, std::allocator<_Ty>>, std::less<_Ty>> &”
        };
        func();
        return 0;
    }
```

If I move the priority_queue declaration into the lambda function ,it compiles perfectly .

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    auto func = [&]()
    {
        priority_queue<int> que;
        vector<int> vec;
        que = decltype(que)(vec.begin(),vec.end());
    };
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

My compiler is the vs2015 community .

Comment: Which compiler are you using? No errors nor warnings with clang.

Comment: @kennytm vs2015 community .

Comment: [builds fine on ideone](https://ideone.com/Wm6hJX).

Comment: No errors compiling with gcc 6.1.1. I see nothing wrong with the shown code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug. For some reason, `decltype(que)` evaluates to `std::priority_queue<int>&` instead of `std::priority_queue<int>`, which causes the error. This may be related to the fact that `que` is passed as reference from within the lambda capture list.

You could also make a mutable lambda:

```
auto func = [que]() mutable
{
    vector<int> vec;
    que = decltype(que)(vec.begin(), vec.end());
};
```

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a MSVC specific compiler error. Assignment isn't allowed because `que` is a `priority_queue<int>&`, use `std::remove_reference` to fix it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    priority_queue<int> que;
    auto func = [&]()
    {
        vector<int> vec;
        que = std::remove_reference<decltype(que)>::type(vec.begin(),vec.end());
    };
    func();
    return 0;
}
```